# How do I hide the "Album" column in iTunes 10?

Tags: itunes, itunes-10

iTunes 10 added an Album column to the list view. It appears that this column shows the album artwork of albums. But I don't want it there. I've tried right clicking on the columns, but I didn't see it in the list as a removable column. I also looked through the view settings and didn't see anything.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a fourth (there were only three before) option on the view selector that allows for the ol list view to be selected.

Comment: That appeared to do it. I missed the new option in the view menu.

Answer (score 1):

On the top right, choose Songs.  Then click on Songs, and underneath that, uncheck "Show Artwork".  That will hide the unwanted Album column as you desire.